# Laravel: Validation

Tags: php, laravel, validation, authentication

I am trying to use validator of laravel, but then it shows an error saying "Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Validator' not found". Is this really because I have to make the Validator Class? If that is so, then how do I make it? Please help. Here are my codes.

web.php

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

Route::get('/', function () {
   return view('login');
});

Route::post('/home', 'loginController@doLogin');
```

loginController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class loginController extends Controller
{
  //
  public function doLogin(){
    $rules=array(
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'password' => 'required|alphaNum|min:3'
    );

    $validator=Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);
    if($validator->fails()){
        return Redirect::to('login')
            ->withErrors($validator)
            ->withInput(Input::except('password'));
    }else{
        $userdata=array(
            'email' => Input::get('login-email'),
            'password' => Input::get('login-password')
        );
        return view('halamanUtama');
    }
  }

}
```

login.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Login</title>

    <!--CSS-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/styles.css') }}" type="text/css">
 </head>
 <body>
   <div class="login-page-frame">
     <div class="header-login-page-frame">
        <h3>Login</h3>
     </div>
     <div class="inner-login-form-frame">
        <form method="post" action="./home" class="login-form">
            {{ csrf_field() }}
            <input type="text" placeholder="email" name="login-email">
            <br>
            <input type="password" placeholder="pass" name="login-password">
            <br>
            <button type="submit" class="btn-login">Log In</button>
        </form>
     </div>
   </div>
 </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

For form validation you could use a Request, you can make this for every form and set specific rules.

More information:"
https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/validation#form-request-validation

Example:

```
class StoreUserRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return Auth::check();
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried to read it, but I have trouble on understanding it. So, if I use this, does that mean, I just have to make the post method on the web.php to direct to StoreUserRequest.authorize just like that?

Comment: No, you let the post method in the web.php still refrence the same function. But instead of a Request paramater you can use the StoreUserRequest paramater. This will validate all the fields. The field validation will be added to the return array in the rules function.

Comment: Alright, sorry about this, I haven't read anything about request so I have some trouble understanding, so that means your method is to first create the form request using php artisan and then make the code like you showed me, and in my doLogin function I give parameter $request, but instead of using Request it used StoreUserRequest, is that how it is? Also, as what you saw, my post method route only shows /home. Will it automatically take my input?

Comment: Remove the validator from the doLogin function. Use StoreUserRequest as a parameter en then you can acces the validated data using the $request variable.

Comment: public function doLogin(StoreUserRequest $request) is how I use it as parameter right? And since you said I should remove the validator and use $request instead, do you mean I will just change my if condition into if($request->fails())? Also, I got an error Class StoreUserRequest does not exist

Comment: It might be smart to just follow the examples in the link provided. Make a test project where you implement the request so you can learn how to do it. I gave you a push in the right direction when it comes to the solution. I cant implement the solution for you.

Comment: Well, actually, the source code I upload is made based on a test project, but it doesn't work. Anyway, thanks for the help until now.

Answer (score 0):

use Validator at the top after namespace

```
use Validator;
```

Is this really because I have to make the Validator Class?

No, Validator is facade you need to use it at top otherwise it'll find in your controller class. that's why you're getting `'App\Http\Controllers\Validator'` not found

Comment: So, I tried it and I got an error because of Input:all(), what should I do about this?

Comment: You can try on $request->all() instead of.

Comment: So, I just realized I haven't read about request, that's why I had trouble understanding this. So, if I get this right, I should add $ request parameter to my doLogin function and then change my Input::all() into $request->all(), is that right? Also, since my post method route is /home, will it just take the inputted data automatically? And, as you can see at my doLogin function, I also get the inputted data and put it into array on the variable $userdata, so since I will use $request, does that mean I can use $request->input('login-email')?

Comment: `$request->login-email` you can try this way

Comment: I tried to do it, but I cannot use $request->login-email. I shows error, so I use the one I said before. But now, I don't understand how come my validator always fails even though my input already fulfilled the requirements. Also, I always get an error if I use redirect::to, do I have to add a use or namespace?